# Deleting a tableview cell with swipe action on the cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to delete a cell with swipe action on it ?

Or are there any other methods for doing so ?

Need Suggestions .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
     // Remove the cell
   }   
}
```